# Is "name" a reserved word in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Rails 4 project and have a model which has a field called *name*.  Unfortunately it appears as though that may be a reserved word.  When I overwrite the model's to_s method it gives me a "stack level too deep" error.  Here's the to_s method:

```
def to_s
    "Category - id: #{id}, name: #{name}, slug: #{slug}"
end
```

Through trial and error I've found out that the field "name" was the problem.  Can I not call a field "name"?  I can't find any documentation about it since searching "field name reserved" shows up a bunch of random results.

Comment: Is `name` an attribute or a method?

Comment: @JoãoDaniel An attribute

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rails 4, but shouldn't you be using `self.name`?

Comment: We frequently name AR attributes 'name'; it hasn't been a problem. Avoid 'key' though.

Comment: @JoãoDaniel, in ruby self is always the context so it's automatically appended.  Same result if I use self

Comment: What happens if you change `name` to `@name`?

Comment: I found the problem.  I had previously assigned self.name to "name" which happens to be a method of the class as well in Rails.  The result is that calling name, ended up calling the method name and it became a recursive mess.

Comment: Yup, "stack level too deep" error occurs when you have an infinite loop on your code. ;)

Comment: @bjhaid What are you talking about? I override `to_s` in most of my Ruby models to present a more meaningful string of text whenever it is being rendered as a `String` to the user.

Comment: @JoshPinter you are correct, that was a dumb comment

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blacklist](http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/), it is not reserved. However, as listed at the bottom, it is a reserved sql name in many modern databases, so you may want to be careful with that.

I have used the attribute "name" and have not run into any problems with it. If you want to be 100% sure, especially when it comes to switching databases, try this:

You can give the db column a different title, such as "user_name", and create an alias for that column inside your model:

```
alias_attribute :name, :username
# pattern is :new_title, :actual_db_column_title
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not reserved. you have to use the keyword `self` to refer to the object that invokes the method. So your `def to_s` should be:

```
def to_s
  "Category - id: #{self.id}, name: #{self.name}, slug: #{self.slug}"
end
```

Comment: self is always the context in a class so you don't need to do this.

Comment: @Nick self is not always the context except it's a Singleton class